# How to TAG webm and weba files/ How to edit metadata of webm and weba files?

Tags: metadata

I use the app MusicBrainz Picard (and easytag) as my windows music-video file tagger. I manage all my media library with this wondeful app. But I've recently accumulated some hundreds of WEBM and WEBA files and I don't know how to make a clean management of this bunch of archives. I want to edit their tags and classify my files according to general and well known rules. I've tried for a result with MKVToolNix and other tools without success. Could you suggest or propose some suitable app? Thanks for your attention.